# iLO 3 CentOS 7 Install hangs

Tags: centos, installation, ilo

HP DL 360 G7

Using the stand-alone program, iLO Integrated Remote Console, I can mount a Virtual Drive and point to the CentOS 7 iso.  I can boot to the iso using the one-time menu (F11) without issue but at some point during the installer it hangs.  Usually, hanging will be either at Network Manager or Plymouth Boot Screen.

Because this server is in a remote location, I'd rather install over iLO.  Otherwise, I'd be sending a DVD to the remote location which is obviously more involved.  I have reset the iLO over ssh but still have the issue.

*BIOS and iLO are from 2018 (newest)*

Has anyone else seen similar issues?

Comment: I have those servers in a C7000 chassis and last week I installed RHEL6/7 though the ILO3 console. Of course I have the latest firmware installed until 2016.

Comment: Yes, make sure all firmware is up to date before trying to install OS.

Comment: BIOS and iLO versions are from 2018 (newest). Just to be more clear, it's not iLO itself freezing per se since the black "screensaver" will go back to console messages if I hit up or down arrows on the keyboard.

Comment: Ohh I see. Since you are able to attach the iso image and boot from it, try to verify if the iso file is not corrupted or if you have a network issue that is causing this problem.

Comment: ISO checksum is good and did the verify process at the ISO boot menu previously which came back good.

Comment: Just took the same iso and installed over iLO 3 on an HP DL 385 G7 that was approximately 1000 miles from here.  A little slow, but not by much and the install completed without issue.  The other is around 2000 miles away.  I've always suspected latency is the real issue but also assumed most modern OS installers took slow read speeds into account.

Comment: So what's the solution?

Comment: My solution (that doesn't answer the question) was to send the DVD to the datacenter and have a tech manually load it.  Would love to hear a real solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while, but I've seen iLO freeze much like that. Before you do anything else make sure you have the latest updates applicable.